# Get enumeration values from Class

Tags: java, enums

Is it possible to get the enumeration values from a Class? Let me elaborate this a bit. If I have an enum for example FooBar, then I can get the values of FooBar by calling FooBar.values() which will return an array with the enumerations (FooBar[]). My problem is, that I have a method which takes as an input parameter a class (Class c) and within the method I check whether or not it is an enum (c.isEnum()). If it is an enum, I would need to somehow get the enum values, the problem is that I don't know quite how to do this, I'm not even totally sure it is possible. So, is it possible and if it is, how can I accomplish this? (Note that the solution needs to be generic, in other words not if-else's).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Um... have you looked at the API doc?

[Class.getEnumConstants()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants())

Comment: Yes, a couple of times and I somehow just kept missing that method o_O

Comment: Just to add an example how to use it: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/reflect/special/enumMembers.html

Answer (score 0):

Edited: You can use c.getClass().getEnumConstants() to get the values of the constants

(it said 'names' instead of 'values' and added some unnecessary stuff)

Comment: Wrong. getEnumConstants() returns the values, not the names - and they're even typed through generics if the class object is, though that probably does not apply in this case.

Comment: Ah, I thought I just tested that, but there's a bug in my quick'n dirty test; sorry about that.